# Does ObjectBox Swift allow conflict strategies for unique entity annotations?

Tags: objectbox, objectbox-java

ObjectBox's Java api has a unique entity annotation which allows you to specify a conflict strategy

```
@Unique(onConflict = ConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
```

Does the Swift api provide similar options for its unique annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet. Chances are good that the next version will.